# typescript: context preservation. Is it a good idea to do it such way?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to keep `this` in class methods.
I can use arrow functions, but I want to override some methods in extended class.

Now I have this solution and it works:

```
class Foo {
    bar = "Context preserved.";
    constructor() {
        this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
    }
    foo() {
        alert(this.bar);
    }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo {
    foo() {
        alert(this.bar + " Class extended");
    }
}

class Bar {
    bar = "Context lost.";
}


let foo = new Foo2();
let bar = new Bar();

foo.foo.apply(bar); // Context preserved. Class extended
```

Is it a good practice to do it such way? If it is, is there some keyword in `typescript` to do it automatically?

like

```
class Foo() {
    public conserved foo() { }
}
```

which generates:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
        this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
    }
    Foo.prototype.foo = function () { };
    return Foo;
}());
```

Comment: This looks kind of odd to me, you know you can use `super` in Typescript: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: @cyrix what looks odd? realization of `Foo2.foo`? It's just an example. I don't understand how `super` can helps with context preservation.

Comment: I don't get why this is anywhere near useful. You are using the class `Bar` which does have nothing to do with `Foo` nor `Foo2` and then you're calling the method `foo` of `Foo2`, while applying `bar` as a context, but you already bound the context of `Foo` to the method `foo`. You could also call `foo.foo()` directly, wouldn't make any difference. which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @cyrix `Bar` here is for checking that context preserved in this example. In real situation context will be changed for example in jquery event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

It's a valid practice and it's being used.
I'm unaware of a way to tell typescript to do this automatically, but you can search the [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) for something like it.

You can have a decorator that does that for you, for example:

```
function construct(constructor: Function, methods: string[], args: any[]) {
    var c: any = function () {
        return constructor.apply(this, args);
    }
    c.prototype = constructor.prototype;
    let instance = new c();
    methods.forEach(name => {
        instance[name] = instance[name].bind(instance);
    });

    return instance;
}

function BindMethods(constructor: Function) {
    const methods = [] as string[];

    Object.keys(constructor.prototype).forEach(name => {
        if (typeof constructor.prototype[name] === "function") {
            methods.push(name);
        }
    });

    return (...args: any[]) => {
        return construct(constructor, methods, args);
    };
}

@BindMethods
class Foo {
    bar = "Context preserved.";

    foo() {
        console.log(this.bar);
    }
}

let foo = new Foo();
setTimeout(foo.foo, 10);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20construct(constructor%3A%20Function%2C%20methods%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%20args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20c%3A%20any%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20constructor.apply(this%2C%20args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c.prototype%20%3D%20constructor.prototype%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20instance%20%3D%20new%20c()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20methods.forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instance%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20instance%5Bname%5D.bind(instance)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20instance%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20BindMethods(constructor%3A%20Function)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20methods%20%3D%20%5B%5D%20as%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Object.keys(constructor.prototype).forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20constructor.prototype%5Bname%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20methods.push(name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20construct(constructor%2C%20methods%2C%20args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40BindMethods%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%20%3D%20%22Context%20preserved.%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.bar)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%3B%0D%0AsetTimeout(foo.foo%2C%2010)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A))

I tested it with this simple use case and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you. I never heard of `decorators` in typescript. It's interesting.

Comment: Oh. So be sure to read [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)